# Weekly Email Newsletter should not escape HTML link

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

On the edit tab of profiles [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/<your_id>`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/), the weekly email newsletter shows plain HTML, instead of a hyperlink:

[image]

Comment: Oh, not another <a href="/questions/lots-of-questions/">HTML escaping bug</a>...

Comment: This ***again?!?!***

Comment: @Doorknob bugs are tricky, you fix one and many times other bug appears. Something like [this](http://mail.colonial.net/~hkaiter/starweb0809/SECTION3/LucyEmilyWeb3A/LucyEmilyWeb3_images/hydra6ow.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot the bug:

```
new 
{ 
  linkStart = 
    @"<a href=""http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=" + 
    NewsletterHelper.CurrentSiteBaseHostAddress + @""" id=""newsletter-preview"">"
    .AsHtml()
}
```

This was fixed in the latest build.